# Repeat a javascript code for different classes without repeating the code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slidetoggle

I have this code were you can click on an img to slide down a class.
Only i want to repeat this process for multiple cases, but the only way I know to do this is to repeat the javascript with different names.

Like this:

```
$( window ).load(function() {
    $('.Img-Toggle').click(function(e){
        $('.slideDown').slideToggle();
    });
    $('.Img-Toggle2').click(function(e){
        $('.slideDown2').slideToggle();
    });
    $('.Img-Toggle3').click(function(e){
        $('.slideDown3').slideToggle();
    });
});
```

I also tried something like this:

```
$('.Img-Toggle .Img-Toggle2 .Img-Toggle3').click(function(e){
    $('.slideDown .slideDown2 .slideDown3').slideToggle();
});
```

but that showed all classes when clicking any of the images (of course)

How can I make 
.Img-Toggle  show .slideDown on click 
and 
.Img-Toggle2 show .slideDown2 on click 
etc...

without having to create a new code every time?

Comment: all can be adjusted based on your markup...please include your HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a common class for the image toggles, and link the related elements using `data-*` attributes

```
<img class="img-toggle" data-link=".slideDown" src="...">
<img class="img-toggle" data-link=".slideDown2" src="...">
```

and write your code once

```
$('.img-toggle').click(function(e){
    var link = $(this).data("link");
    $(link).slideToggle();
});
```